# Python Pandas Dataframe get count of rows after filtering using values from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, rows

I have a dataframe that looks like below.
I want to build a data profile by getting the following counts.

1) count of **unique** student IDs(Number of students) 
My Answer works:

```
print(len(df['Student ID'].unique()))
```

2)count of unique student IDs **where** International=N (Number of Non international students)

My answer does not work: `print(len(df1.loc[(df1['Student ID'].unique())['International Student'] == N]))`

3)count of unique student IDs where International=N & ATAR is **not null**(number of non-international students who has an ATAR)

4) count of unique student IDs where ATAR is **between** 0-50

some other questions:

5) how can I **create a new dataframe** with only unique Student IDs with all other columns, dropping all rows per student ID after the first

answers to questions 2-5 would be much appreciated.

```
Student_ID            International       marks      ATAR

119                   N                    60         80
119                   N                    70         80
119                   N                    75         80
129                   Y                    78         75
129                   Y                    60         75 
155                   Y                    85         
155                   Y                    80
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'International': ['N', 'N', 'N', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'], 
'marks': [60, 70, 75, 78, 60, 85, 80], 
'Student_ID': [119, 119, 130, 140, 155, 155, 155], 
'ATAR': [80.0, 20.0, np.nan, 50.0, 15.0, np.nan, np.nan]
}).reindex_axis(['Student_ID','International','marks','ATAR'], axis=1)

print (df)
   Student_ID International  marks  ATAR
0         119             N     60  80.0
1         119             N     70  20.0
2         130             N     75   NaN
3         140             Y     78  50.0
4         155             Y     60  15.0
5         155             Y     85   NaN
6         155             Y     80   NaN
```

Need [`Series.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) mainly with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for return one column (`Series`), last [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for new `df1`:

```
print(df['Student_ID'].nunique())
4
print(df.loc[df['International'] == 'N', 'Student_ID'].nunique())
2
print(df.loc[(df['International'] == 'N') & (df['ATAR'].notnull()), 'Student_ID'].nunique())
1
print(df.loc[df['ATAR'].between(0,50), 'Student_ID'].nunique())
3

df1 = df.drop_duplicates('Student_ID')
print (df1)
   Student_ID International  marks  ATAR
0         119             N     60  80.0
2         130             N     75   NaN
3         140             Y     78  50.0
4         155             Y     60  15.0
```

Comment: No problem, it is my university and shorcuts is BA STU ;)

Comment: :D for me it means BA(Business Analytics) student. thank u. u too

Comment: :D :D Ya, it is nice :)